# Deploying with Heroku using a database.yaml file not in github repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, github

When pushing to Github, I want to .gitignore my database.yaml file so that I don't publically expose my production database password.  But I need that password to be available to Heroku for when the app is running in production.

I could set environment variables in heroku, but that strikes me as unsecure.  Any able to get on my computer could run a single command in terminal and reveal the password variable.

When dealing with Github and Heroku, it is possible to write code that specifies that certain files should be ignored when pushing to github but not ignored when pushing to heroku?

Comment: Heroku doesn't use your `config/database.yml` file.

Comment: What?!  I had no idea.  So it's essentially pointless to password protect your production database it you're pushing to heroku?

Comment: Nope! You don't even need a `production:` entry in `config/database.yml` if you're only deploying to Heroku.

Comment: Let's be clear.. even if you don't use database.yml, your production database should be password protected.  For instance, for a postgres database, DATABASE_URL is in the format postgres://username:password@host:port/database_name .

Comment: Could you explain that in a little more detail?  I'm a little confused.  (Or if you can recommend a piece of documentation, I can read up on it there.)

Comment: Heroku will automagicly override your `database.yml` file. It gets the settings to use from your `DATABASE_URL` env variable, so if it looks like: `mysql2://user:pass@host:port`, Heroku will use the adapter `mysql2`, the user `user`, the pass `pass`, the host `host`, and the port `port`. Most addons (ClearDB, Heroku Postgres) will set the `DATABASE_URL`, so you should be fine.

Comment: database.yml shouldn't be a problem but what about for other yml files? Do we have an answer for his more general question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once someone gets access to your host, it's basically over.  Either approach, environment variables or a database.yml file, will still be retrievable if someone has access to your box.

I would recommend using environment variables in Heroku to store your database credentials.  As you know, you should never check in production credentials into any repository.